# Angular 5 - Separate or segregate the app.component for different folders

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I am using Angular 5.2+ in my new project and i am also new to this technology.

Here is the folder structure of my ang project:-

[image]

Currently my **app.component.html** looks like this:-

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-leftnav></app-leftnav>
<div class="container body-content"> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

These selectors such as `<app-header> , <app-leftnav>` are separate components.

The **app.component.ts** looks like this :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent  { }
```

The **admin-routing.module.ts** looks like this :-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { UserSearchModule } from './userSearch/userSearch.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [UserSearchModule],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AdminRoutingModule {
 }
```

Now the main issue:- I want to have the separate app.component.html file for the admin and the client folders. Because both the admin and client have different page structures. How can i make the further abstraction of app.component.html into admin and client ?

How do i make the app.component.html content specific to admin and client areas.

Or can i control the rendering of app-header, app-leftnav w.r.t. the admin and client routes ?

Please suggest the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app.component is the entry point of your application, then you shouldn't try to make it different for your user profiles.

Instead, you could define a layout for every user profile (a component with a `<router-outlet>` inside)

Then define your routes like this :

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    loadChildren: '../admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  }, {
    path: 'client',
    component: ClientLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [ClientGuard],
    loadChildren: '../client/client.module#ClientModule'
  }
```

Comment: In my example, I assume you lazy load your modules, which is generally the best solution as it quickens your application's first loading

Comment: yeh, i am doing lazy loading of feature modules in my app.

Comment: Please suggest, where do i add your suggested routing path. I added the code for the admin-routing.module.ts also to the main question.

Comment: i suggest you add this routing path in an intermediary module (you could name it `Core`) that would hold root routes, layouts, and global services (guards, interceptors, etc...). It allows to separate the concerns : `AppModule` for bootstrap, `CoreModule` for your root logic. Your admin routing module would contain routes relative to the parent module

Comment: I also suggest you read this excellent article : https://www.technouz.com/4644/angular-5-app-structure-multiple-modules/

Comment: after spending some time in configuring the route paths, it worked for me. The article is really good for building module based apps.